# How to check all RDP connections from central server

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remote-access

We currently have multiple servers where multiple users use the same account to log into a server.

Eg.
Say there are 3 Users ABC, XYZ, MNP where all users  log into a server with the same user KLM. But they cannot be logged in at the same time, since the allowed users is set to 1.

Now what we want is that when ABC logs in with KLM, we want to write to a file that ABC logged into the server. Same goes for XYZ and MNP.

We can monitor per server by installing a custom service to monitor the sessions. But we want to be able to do this for all servers without installing the service on each one. Is there a way that we can use the Domain Controller that all the servers are under, to check who is logging in to what?

Comment: They're all logging in as KLM. How do you presume to identify that it's ABC or XYZ or MNP logging in as KLM?

Comment: There are so many better ways to do this.  Why are you doing it this way?  And what's your actual end goal here?

Comment: @joeqwerty we want get the local machine name that is used to log into the server.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Our end goal is to keep a log file of who is logging into the servers. This is for auditing purposes.

Comment: Then why don't you have the users log in with their user accounts instead of a common account?

Comment: The common account is for people that are working on the same thing. So that what ever is stored on that account can be seen by all.

Comment: Setup a Remote Desktop gateway.  Run all access to the servers through the gateway.  Your data will be in the logs.

Comment: @Dreamer78692 If you want all users to access the same data, wouldn't it be simpler to create one folder that all of them can access?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this can be done by two ways, but not sure about using domain controller on this.

Try using "Task Scheduler" on the server and perform the below settings once in all the servers. The "Task Scheduler" can watch and trigger an action when a user connected remotely.

Task Scheduler > Create a Task > Name the task > Trigger tab > New > "Begin the task" drop down > On connection to user session > refer the below screenshot and apply required settings.

[image]

Now go to Action tab > write a simple batch file to capture the data and time in a text file using "Start a Program" option or "Send an email" option as per your requirement. Refer the screenshot and apply the settings.

[image]

Or, please use the below command line query to know the instant information about who is currently logged in remotely to the server and from where. Please note that, you need to have 'Psexec.exe' file in your machine to run it from the command line.

```
psexec \\remoteMachine -u user -p pswrd netstat | find "3389"
```

Hope this helps.